# Multiple Fields in For Expression

Tags: scala, dictionary

Given a List of `JsObject`'s, I'd like to convert it to a `Map[String, JsValue]`, and then iterate through each map's key-value pair, making a JsObject per pair. Finally, I'd like to put all of these JsObject's into a `List[JsObject]`.

Below is my attempt with a for expression.

```
def getObjMap(obj: JsObject): Option[Map[String, JsValue]] = obj match { 
   case JsObject(fields) => Some(fields.toMap)
   case _ => None
}

def createFields(x: (String, JsValue)): JsObject = Json.obj("n" -> x._1, 
                                                            "v" -> x._2)    
val objects: List[JsObject] = foo()

val res: List[JsObject] = for {
                            obj <- objects
                            map <- getObjMap(obj)
                            mapField <- map
                          } yield(createFields(mapField))
```

However, I'm getting a compile-time error on the `mapField <- map` line.

```
[error] ...\myApp\app\services\Test.scala:65: type mismatch; 
[error]  found   : scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[play.api.libs.
                                                                  json.JsObject] 
[error]  required: Option[?]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is coming from the fact that the for comprehension starts by working over a List, then ends up working over an Option (from `getObjMap`). The type of construct needs to remain constant across the whole for comprehension. Calling `.toList` on the result of the `getObjMap` call fixes this:

```
val res: List[JsObject] = for {
                            obj <- objects
                            map <- getObjMap(obj).toList
                            mapField <- map
                          } yield(createFields(mapField))
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out. On a side note, how does my code look? Is it idomatic or garbage? What could I do better?

Comment: That worked, thanks, Shadowlands. I didn't include it, but I have my `createFields(...)` function contains a third field (`l` (lineNumber) ) where, for each obj in objects, I need to increment a lineNumber. Currently, I increment the lineNumber at the beginning of my `getObjMap(...`) method. How can I still use an incrementing lineNumber with the for expression?